# Modify auto detect username and password for password saving suggestion on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am implementing the reset password function for my website. When users use this function, they will get a link through an email with params to click, like:
http://wallpaper.local/confirm-re-password?email=batv@tohsoft.com&reset_code=1f18d2f9f0

Access the link, users will get this form
[Reset Password Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G03dT.png)

Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRePass">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button id="btn-close-register-modal" type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </button>
              <div class="image text-center">
                  <img :src="'/images/popup_reset.png'" alt="Register">
              </div>
              <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Re-Pass</h4>
              <div class="list-field">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reset_code" :value="reset_code" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" :value="email" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Re-Type Password">
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin: 0 auto;">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success-toh" v-on:click="rePass">Reset Password</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As it can be seen, the "code" field doesn't have any words relating to username, but when I click submit, in the saving pass suggestion, Chrome suggest the code as Username.

[Chrome password suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usV1Q.png)

Is there anyway to modify this Chrome suggestion to fill email address into the input field? Firefox, Opera, Edge do suggest the email instead of the reset code.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The [autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) might do this.

Comment: As I understand, the [autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) is for autocompleting the form, not the browser suggestion?

Comment: Chrome may use it for type hinting for that dialog.

Comment: Do things change if you remove the disabled attribute from the email field? And since disabled means the values won’t actually be included in the form submission to begin with, you might as well show the code using something else than an input field.

Comment: @Maviss have you tried using input type ="hidden" instead of type="text" for the code field?

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I tried removing "disable" and it works.